I accidently turned on Android Talk back
How did talkback get turned on and how do I turn it off when my screen stops registering inputs?
There is another question on this forum that answers this but those solutions didn't work for me and I am not allowed to post the solution that I found because of reputation points!  I will see if this forum at least lets me answer my own question.
